# Dont expand BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH if SEQ is empty

Tags: c, boost, c-preprocessor

If the argument list is empty

```
#define key_evaluate(r, key, sig) key |= 1 << sig;
#define getKey(...)\
({\
      ComponentKey key = 0;\
      BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(key_evaluate, key, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))
      key;\
})
    
int main(void)
{
     getKey();
}
```

expands to

```
int main(void)
{
    ({ 
         ComponentKey key = 0; 
         key |= 1 << ;
         key; 
    })
}
```

but I would like to have it expand to nothing if _*VA_ARGS*_ is empty.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29227073/boost-pp-expand-sequence-in-the-empty-sequence-case) answers a question of this type, but if I use this instead

```
#define key_evaluate(r, key, sig) key |= 1 << sig;
#define convertToKey(...) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(key_evaluate, key, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))
#define components_convertToKey(...)\
    ({\
        ComponentKey key = 0;\
        BOOST_PP_IF(BOOST_PP_EQUAL(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_SIZE((,##__VA_ARGS__)), 1), \
        BOOST_PP_EXPAND, convertToKey) (__VA_ARGS__) \
        key;\
    })
```

I get this error: `error: ‘BOOST_PP_EXPAND’ undeclared`.
This means BOOST_PP_EXPAND is not replaced by the Preprocessor, because BOOST_PP_EXPAND is used elsewhere, which means it is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know.

I DO know

- that macros are often problematic
- that braced-group expressions are non-standard

It looks like you're trying to combine a number of integral sigs into a key mask, so making up an example could look like:

```
enum SigKeys {
    key0 = 1,
    key1 = 2,
    key2 = 4,
    key3 = 8,
    key4 = 16,
};
```

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a86dd15c9501708d)**

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void) {
    std::cout << "key1, key2: " << (key1 + key2) << " == " << getKey(1, 2) << "\n";
    std::cout << "key2, key4: " << (key2 + key4) << " == " << getKey(4, 2) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
key1, key2: 6 == 6
key2, key4: 20 == 20
```

### RETAKE, NO MACROS

Assuming your compiler is up to snuff, you could simply write that as:

```
template <typename... T>
constexpr ComponentKey getKey(T&&... sig) {
    return (0 | ... | (1 << sig));
}
```

It will be standard, portable, compile in a fraction of the time, be more readable, contexpr and [optimizable](https://godbolt.org/z/6hxGjq).

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dda526952267d41c)**

### What If Your Compiler Old

Even then you can have it better:

```
ComponentKey getKey(std::initializer_list<int> sig) {
    return std::accumulate(sig.begin(), sig.end(), 0,
            [](int r, int s) { return r | (1 << s); });
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f7b0b9893521377)** as well. Unsurprisingly it will [optimize just the same](https://godbolt.org/z/3bTdbr).

> If you prefer without `std::accumulate`: [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2afee654a5e2d618) and [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/sGG6jo)
>
> ```
> ComponentKey getKey(std::initializer_list<int> sig) {
>     ComponentKey r = 0;
>     for (auto& s : sig)
>         r |= 1 << s;
>     return r;
> }
> ```